Do i have to bury electrical PVC conduit from house to generator? i need to go about 5 feet from corner of house
i need to connect my new generator to electrical and natural gas.  the generator is about 5 feet from the corner of my house.  Do i need to do the electrical underground or is just 1 foot above ground and use stakes to support ok?

One foot above would be not good.  Besides a simple trip hazard, the wire/conduit would be subject to being run into by anything that can fit.  Time to get digging.

Could you share a picture or describe the area? Electrical installations need to be supported and protected from damage, but outdoor conduit doesn't automatically have to be buried. It may be that a simple structure built of strut or other material would be appropriate.

If digging is not wanted, a fence/wall(3 or 4ft) would probably do to place the conduit on, but just a couple of stakes would be a no.

See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/283370/18078
